# esBuild serve over HTTPS

Tags: https, esbuild, devserver

esBuild makes it pretty easy to serve http requests over it's own dev server, e.g.

```
require('esbuild').serve({
  servedir: 'www',
}, {
  entryPoints: ['src/app.js'],
  outdir: 'www/js',
  bundle: true,
}).then(server => {
  // Call "stop" on the web server to stop serving
  server.stop()
})
```

How do I enable HTTPS serving in this case? I can make it serve on port 443, but how do I attach a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @DavidMeents I ended up using esBuild in watch mode `esbuild.build({watch: true})` in one terminal and running [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) in another. It makes running SSL [pretty straightforward](https://github.com/http-party/http-server#tlsssl)

Comment: `$ http-server -p 8000 -S dist/`

Comment: Just for info, the related ticket on github where the esbuild maintainer mentioned this is out of scope in his opinion (which is a bit disappointing imho): https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1845

Answer (score 0):

I've found two solutions, that worked for me:

1. using [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy#https---http), in an extra file or inside your esbuild config. The limitation I've found here, you cannot use esbuild's `--serve` and `--watch` together (https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/805), so if you need auto reload/live server functionality, you have to create this on your own, which is slightly complicated (https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/802)

   ```
   httpProxy.createServer({
     target: {
       host: 'localhost',
       port: 3000
     },
     ssl: {
       key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem', 'utf8'),
       cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem', 'utf8')
     }
   }).listen(3001);
   ```
2. Using [servor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/servor), here with npm scripts only, but you can also use servor in an esbuild config. Be aware to name your certificate files `servor.crt` and `servor.key` (https://github.com/lukejacksonn/servor/issues/79). I prefer this solution because of even less dependencies, simpler setup and auto reload/live server already build in.

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "build": "esbuild --bundle src/index.tsx --outfile=public/bundle.js",
     "start": "npm run server & npm run build -- --watch",
     "server": "servor public index.html 3000 --reload --secure"
   }
   ```